# Quartz.Net CronTime IsSatisfiedBy() never returns true?

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

I try to make something simple with the Quartz.Net's `CronExpression.IsSatisfiedBy()` function. But this function is always return `false`. Even when I used every second expression `"* * * * * ?"`. Sample code is following:

```
//every second cron expression
var cron = new Quartz.CronExpression("* * * * * ?");

// all the results are always false
var result1 = cron.IsSatisfiedBy(DateTimeOffset.Now);
var result2 = cron.IsSatisfiedBy(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
var result3 = cron.IsSatisfiedBy(DateTime.Now);
var result4 = cron.IsSatisfiedBy(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Quartz.NET [issue](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/349) about milliseconds.
To workaround this problem you can use `IsSatisfiedBy` method with time without milliseconds. Like that:

```
var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
//no milliseconds time
var test = new DateTimeOffset(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, 
                              now.Minute, now.Second, now.Offset);

//every second cron expression
var cron = new Quartz.CronExpression("* * * * * ?");
//hey, that's true!
var result = cron.IsSatisfiedBy(test);
```